# Power BI many to many issue to resolve

Tags: sql-server, many-to-many, powerbi

I realize that Power BI does not resolve many to many relationships. I am new to database and Power BI and was wondering if there is any way to resolve the problem I am having. 
I am pulling a sales table from my database which give me

```
Starting_Date_of_week   Actual  ShipGrp
```

I have 5 shipgrps so I am getting 5 rows for each week.

Now I hve a budgeting excel, which has 1 row for each week, but 5 different columns for each group. So I pivoted the table to have the table similar to my query table. But now the tables are not joining. Are there any ways for these tables to join. Am I missing out anything or any better way to create visualizations for these tables to interact with each other in the charts?

I want the filters to interact between charts and the groups, and basically compare the budgeting excel and the actuals in the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BI Designer many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30869837/bi-designer-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: You can introduce a third table with unique keys to join on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 3rd table with unique values (reference the original table and use remove duplicates).
Qlik(view or sense) solve this problem automatically, and their desktop is also free, as Power BI desktop.

Comment: Yes. This is the solution I used